# MVC4 Postback Viewmodel is null, even with HiddenFor, any ideas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, html-helper

Even though I have added @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SomeObject.ID)

My Viewmodel is still null after Postback.

Here's some of my Razor code:

```
@model Application.ViewModels.AppViewModel

...

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, null))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Participants</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SomeObject.ID)
     ... (Other Hidden items)

... (Displaying some stuff)

}
```

My Controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Draw(AppViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.SomeObject != null) model.RunDraw(model.SomeObject.ID);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

The Model is valid but always Null

Comment: the whole model is null, or just the ID?
What Type is the ID? Maybe post the model too, and it will be more obvious